# WYSIHTML5 Getting HTML and Plain Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysihtml5

Just starting working with **WYSIHTML5** for my Rails app, and so far it's awesome. I'm having some trouble grabbing the text value of the content however. I was to save both the HTML and a plain-text version of the content inside the wysihtml5 box. I thought `.html()` would give me the HTML version and `.val()` or `.text()` would let me retrieve the plain text version. However, `.val()` gives me the HTML version and `.text()` returns an empty string. Not sure what's going on, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From the jQuery API doc: The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method.

Comment: If val isn't working for you try `innerText`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code work and overcome this issue. This method more fast than jQuery when trying access the content - if who wants check the written text content's length.

```
var writtenTextContent = document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.textContent;
var textLength = writtenTextContent.length;
```